# PANDAS ERROR:' With n_samples=1, test_size=0.25 and train_size=None,(...) Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.'

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am using the following code and please see the error below.
the code:

[please see my data in this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OT7Pg.png)

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Ecommerce Customers')
df.head()

X=[['Avg. Session Length', 'Time on App','Time on Website']]

y=['Yearly Amount Spent']

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=101)
```

output:

```
ValueError: With n_samples=1, test_size=0.25 and train_size=None, the resulting train set will be empty. Adjust any of the aforementioned parameters.
```

I've read in the forum to extend the data in this case but I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: It seems there is only 1 row in your dataframe. Can you show us the data?

Comment: You offered a single example row. And asked for a 75 - 25 split. Maybe you were hoping for 3/4 row to train on, and a 1/4 row of test data to validate against? Consider broadening your horizons, and obtaining more than a couple of example rows.

Comment: I uploaded a photo of my data in the original post.please check.. i tried with different datasets(all is with more than 100rows) and all of them gets the same error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add 'df' when creating X and y:

```
X=df[['Avg. Session Length', 'Time on App','Time on Website']]

y=df['Yearly Amount Spent']
```

This way X and y are Dataframes/Series. Otherwise they are just lists with column names in it.